# How to go from sorting numbers to sorting alphabetically in C++

Tags: c++, sorting

I revised this question after pondering what I would like some help with. They way I have currently only sorts text from a file based on their tax_rate a.k.a by numbers. I need to sort context inside a text file like this:

Original context:

> bLack car 200.00
>   jumbo Car 82.00
>   AlPha caR 2932.00

Sorted context:

> AlPha caR 2932.00
>   bLack car 200.00
>   jumbo Car 82.00

A code I used when I was using this code to sort by tax rate.

> ```
> void sort(string county[], double tax_rate[])
> {
>      for (int i=0; i<COUNTY_MAX; i++)
>      {
>           for (int j=i+1; j<COUNTY_MAX; j++)
>           {
>                if (tax_rate[i] < tax_rate[j])
>                {
>                     //Swap tax_rate
>                     double temp = tax_rate[i];
>                     tax_rate[i] = tax_rate[j];
>                     tax_rate[j] = temp;
>
>                     //Swap county
>                     string t = county[i];
>                     county[i]= county[j];
>                     county[j]= t;
>                }
>           }
>      }
> }
> ```

How different would it be to sort from numbers to sorting by words via Alphabetical?
If you see anything unclear in the question, let me know so that I can clear it up. Thanks.

Comment: Where exactly is the hold-up for you?

Comment: My old code sorts through a text file's numbers while the new code I'm am trying to making it sort through the county via alphabetic. Obviously this sorting function that I currently have only does for the tax rate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not at all. `string` allows comparison by <. You just need to use `county` in your comparison.

The way comparison works is, strings earlier in the dictionary would be considered as "lesser" than than those later. So it'd work just as you expect.

```
void sort(string county[], double tax_rate[])
{
   for (int i=0; i<COUNTY_MAX; i++)
   {
      for (int j=0; j<COUNTY_MAX; j++)
      {
           if (county[i] < county[j])
           {
                //Swap tax_rate
                double temp = tax_rate[i];
                tax_rate[i] = tax_rate[j];
                tax_rate[j] = temp;

                //Swap county
                string t = county[i];
                county[i]= county[j];
                county[j]= t;
           }
      }
   }
}
```

[Running code](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/0ee9b1272a438bff)

Comment: I tried that but it would just run as it normally did. On top of that, would I have to swap the order of the swaps under the if command?

Comment: I am not sure I fully understood your concern, but I hope the code clears it up.

Comment: I tried exactly like that code you just posted and its not sorting the text file correctly. It's sorting by the tax rate instead of the county.

Comment: The issue was with your sorting algorithm. `j` should start from 0, not `i+1`. I've updated the code.

Comment: That actually worked, thanks. Not completely sorted the right way, but its starting to sort using the county variable now. It sorted the 1st two in the file but the next two aren't sorted and then the rest of the file continues the sorting trend left by the 1st two county.

Comment: It's sorting from alphabetically but first its going through A-Z uppercase and once that's done, then it does it continues with a-z lowercase. I want them to be sort regarded less of upper or lower case.

Comment: change everything to lowercase or uppercase.

Comment: Is there a way to make it recognize lowercase and uppercase as the same?